# Hadoop MapReduce DistributedCache usage

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-caching, bloom-filter

I'm trying to reproduce the **Bloom Filtering example** of **MapReduce Design Pattern** book.
In the following, I will show only the code of interest:

```
public static class BloomFilteringMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, NullWritable>
{
    private BloomFilter filter = new BloomFilter();

    protected void setup( Context context ) throws IOException
    {
        URI[] files = DistributedCache.getCacheFiles( context.getConfiguration() );
        String path = files[0].getPath();
        System.out.println( "Reading Bloom Filter from: " + path );
        DataInputStream strm = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream( path ) );
        filter.readFields( strm );
        strm.close();
    }
    //...
}
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    Job job = new Job( new Configuration(), "description" );
    URI uri = new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter");
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile( uri, job.getConfiguration() );
    //...
}
```

When I try to execute it, **I receive the following error: 

*java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/draxent/comment.bloomfilte***r

But executing the command:

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls
```

I can see the file:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 draxent supergroup        405 2015-11-25 17:12 /user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter
```

So I am quite sure the problem is on the line:

```
URI uri = new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter");
```

But I have tried several different configuration, like: 
*"hdfs://user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter"* 
*"/user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter"*  
*"comment.bloomfilter"*

And no one works.

I have tried to look up at the [cfeduke implementation](https://github.com/cfeduke/mrdpatterns/), but I was no able to solve my problem.

**Answer comments:**

- *ravindra*: URI files[0] contains the string element passed in the main;
- *Manjunath Ballur*: yea, you are right. But since the file exists (you can see it from *bin/hadoop fs -ls*) this means that is a problem of the string **path** passed to *FileInputStream*. But I'm passing the string to that like always. I checked, the path value is: *comment.bloomfilter*... so it has to be right.

Comment: Can you debug the values you have received from URI[] files call?. I suspect that context was not properly set.

Comment: The problem is not with line:     URI uri = new URI("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter");. This line can throw only "URISyntaxException". The problem seems to be with line:         DataInputStream strm = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream( path ) );.  FileInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

The Distributed Cache API has been deprecated.

You can extend the same functionality using the new API.Check the documentation here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html

In the driver code:-

`Job job = new Job();
...
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());`

In the mapper setup method :-

```
Path[] localPaths = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:
remove the line with `URI uri = new URI(...`  and change the next line to:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("/user/draxent/comment.bloomfilter").toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
```